# Are IO/file IO operations given more priority than CPU operations in a C++ program?

Tags: c++, operating-system, kernel

If that is so why is that the case? I am pretty sure it should not, but do the priorities differ by the OS?

Comment: What made you think that?

Comment: I was reading somewhere online, not sure where, and so I thought so. Is the answer that CPU bound stuff(maybe some mathematical calculation say) is given more priority than writing to the file/screen?

Comment: It seems you have a number of misconceptions about prioritisation. But it might be too broad to try and clarify them. Perhaps you could rather explain the specific problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: I honestly can't understand what you mean by priority in this context. Do you mean done first? Done faster? I can't get your question to make sense.

Answer (score 0):

I/O operations are CPU operations.

This all system specific but in general, the CPU directs the drive to do something. The drive responds by triggering an interrupt when it has completed. The CPU then interrupts what it is doing and handles the drive request.

Interrupt handling generally take priority over everything else. And processors generally have multiple levels of interrupts with different priorities,